# How do I increment my array counter to move to the next element in the array in this code?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have the routine below where I'm copying all the contents of a sheet if the sheet name matches the array name.

I've got the sheets copying to the destination, but I'm not getting the array value curRow to increment.

What am I missing here?

```
Sub test()

    Dim curRow As Integer, CurrentRow As Integer, LastRow As Integer, LastRow2 As Integer
    Dim activeWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set activeWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arArray As Variant

    Sheets("Total Tabs").Activate
    arArray = Sheets("Total Tabs").Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    curRow = 1
    CurrentRow = 2

    For curRow = 1 To LastRow

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
'            If curRow <> 1 Then
 '               curRow = curRow + 1

 '          End If

            If ws.name = arArray(curRow, 1) Then
                LastRow2 = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                For CurrentRow = 2 To LastRow2
                    ws.Range("A" & CurrentRow & ":N" & CurrentRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Reps No Longer Here").Range("A" & CurrentRow)

                    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
                Next
                    curRow = curRow + 1
            End If

        Next ws
    Next curRow

End Sub
```

UPDATE:
Here is the final code that I have and works as it should. Included is also the ability to hide the tab once it has been processed.

I'm sure it can be optimized, but here it is:

```
Sub CombineDataToRNLH()

    Dim curRow As Integer, CurrentRow As Integer, LastRow As Integer, LastRow2 As Integer
    Dim activeWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set activeWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arArray As Variant
    Dim pasterow As Integer
    Dim RepName As String

'Activate the sheet with the list and then read the list of names
'straight into an array

    Sheets("Total Tabs").Activate
    arArray = Sheets("Total Tabs").Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

'Find last element in the array and calculate as rows

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    curRow = 1      'Index for evaluating array elements
    CurrentRow = 2  'Counter for use in processing all rows in matched sheet to destination sheet

    LastRow2 = 1    'Find number of rows in the matched tab
    pasterow = 2    'Counter to ensure that I'm always copying data to the first available row

'Set up loop so that I can match array elements to individual sheet names

    For curRow = 1 To LastRow

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

            If ws.name = arArray(curRow, 1) Then
                LastRow2 = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                For CurrentRow = 2 To LastRow2
                    ws.Range("A" & CurrentRow & ":N" & CurrentRow).Copy _
                    Destination:=Sheets("Reps No Longer Here").Range("A" & pasterow)

                    If CurrentRow = LastRow2 Then
                        curRow = curRow + 1
                        pasterow = pasterow + 1
                        ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden 'Set it to very hidden.

                        Exit For
                    End If

                    pasterow = pasterow + 1

                Next


            End If
        Next ws
    Next curRow
    Sheets("How To").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, let's check what you mean: when you increment `curRow = curRow + 1`, what's your intention? Isn't `Next curRow` enough to go to the next row?

Comment: don't forget also that Integer variables can hold values between -32,768 and 32,767, while Long variables can range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. If your curRow goes beyond 32,767 you will have a problem too.

Comment: Hi All!  THanks for the help and the streamlining. I went back to the drawing board and re-wrote from scratch. I've got it doing what I want now, and now going to hide the sheets processed for printing purposes later. I'll post the final code once I finish it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code can be simplified and streamlined a bit.  From what I gather, you want to loop through some sheets (as defined in your aaArray variable) and copy the data to a "Reps No Longer Here" tab.  See if this does what you're after:

```
Sub test()

    Dim LastRow     As Long, _
        LastRow2    As Long

    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim arArray     As Variant
    Dim sheetName   As Variant

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    With Sheets("Total Tabs")

        arArray = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        For Each sheetName In arArray
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = Sheets(sheetName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If ws Is Nothing Then
             ' we don't need to do anything since the sheet doesn't exist
            Else

                LastRow2 = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                LastRow = Sheets("Reps No Longer Here").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                ws.Range("A2:N" & LastRow2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Reps No Longer Here").Range("A" & LastRow)
            End If

        Next sheetName
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```